# Display invoice inside CodeIgniter view page

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

I have some problem creating invoice in CodeIgniter view page. I want to show records from database to display in php view. As mentioned below in picture. [image]

Any relevant idea how to do it? is there any library for display this formatted view?

Thanks in advance
Shinoy

Comment: what you want to downloadable pdf of invoice?

Comment: No, I want to display in a view page

Comment: then what is the problem??

Comment: The above picture mentioned in the question is drawn in wireframe tool . I want to show it in php view .

Comment: simple html will do, right?